# How to fix blazor error " The namespace 'Razor' already contains a definition for 'Template' "

Tags: c#, blazor

After creating a new blazor component i get this error:

```
 The namespace 'Razor' already contains a definition for 'Template'
```

Is it a bug with auto generation or something? How can i fix it in blazor?
It appears very often and i have no idea why. 
Blazor is pretty new framework, can somebody defeated this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    ...
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Adding AddRazorSupportForMvc fixes the issue for me